# make a button that will run .py

Tags: python, html, django

I'm making a website that will take 2 input files and return the differences between those file as an output. I already made the textcompare program in python and the first two webpages that will take the uploaded files and store it in one folder with the textcompare.py The last webpage that i'm having problem with has only one button that says execute. The main idea behind this button is when I click it, it will run textcompare.py, the program produces an output, then it will send it to the user to download it. Problem is, I dont know how to define a class that will run textcompare .py. I'm new to python and django so thanks for bearing with me.

In the execute.html I have

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <div>
      <form action= '{% url my_view_name%}' method="POST">
          <input type="submit" value="Execute" id="Execute" />
      </form>
    </div>


  {% if uploaded_file_url %}

  {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

In the views.py I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from uploads.core.models import Document
from uploads.core.forms import DocumentForm


def home(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'core/home.html', { 'documents': documents })


def uploadOne(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        modified_name = "file1.csv".format()
        filename = fs.save(modified_name, myfile)


        #filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)

        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'core/uploadTwo.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'core/uploadOne.html')

def uploadTwo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        modified_name = "file2.csv".format()
        filename = fs.save(modified_name, myfile)

        #filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)

        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'core/uploadTwo.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'core/uploadTwo.html')

def execute(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import TextCompare.py


def my_view_name(request):
    #your script contents will go here. not literally but this is where gist of script should run
    # calculate the difference and put it in context var and return as follows
    diff = 
    # this program is to compare 2 files and extract the differences in a new file
    # the line old.csv, new.csv, and update.csv can be replaced to another type of file such as .txt
    with open('file1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as t2: # here i open 2 files and make python read it
        file1 = t1.readlines() # read lines from 1st file
        file2 = t2.readlines() # read lines from 2nd file

    with open('difference.csv', 'w') as outFile: # create output file called with update.csv
        for line in filetwo: #for statement
            if line not in fileone: # if line is not same
                outFile.write(line) # print the output()

        context['diff'] = diff
    return render(request, 'core/uploadOne.html', context)
```

and urls.py I have

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from uploads.core import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^uploads/uploadOne/$', views.uploadOne, name='uploadOne'),
    url(r'^uploads/uploadTwo/$', views.uploadTwo, name='uploadTwo'),
    url(r'^uploads/execute/$', views.execute, name='execute'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is the textcompare.py

```
# this program is to compare 2 files and extract the differences in a new file
# the line old.csv, new.csv, and update.csv can be replaced to another type of file such as .txt
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as t2: # here i open 2 files and make python read it
    fileone = t1.readlines() # read lines from 1st file
    filetwo = t2.readlines() # read lines from 2nd file

with open('difference.csv', 'w') as outFile: # create output file called with update.csv
    for line in filetwo: #for statement
        if line not in fileone: # if line is not same
            outFile.write(line) # print the output
```

I believe the urls.py is good but views.py and execute.html is not ready. If anyone could help me defining the class and going through execute.html that'd be awesome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay it does not work like that. You are telling your form to go on uri my_view_name. Make a a route with this name in url.py. define a function which gets invoked on that url. Your url pattern would look like

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from uploads.core import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^uploads/uploadOne/$', views.uploadOne, name='uploadOne'),
    url(r'^uploads/uploadTwo/$', views.uploadTwo, name='uploadTwo'),
    url(r'^uploads/execute/$', views.execute, name='execute'),
    url(r'^my_view_name/$', views.my_view_name, name='my_view_name'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## In your views.py

```
def my_view_name(request):
    #your script contents will go here. not literally but this is where gist of script should run
    # calculate the difference and put it in context var and return as follows
    diff = yourscript()
    context['diff'] = diff
    return render(request, 'core/uploadOne.html', context)
```

PS: This is absolutely not the way to do this, Ideally it should be upload files together and calculate the difference right then, but Since I do not know extent of what your application is doing I would not get into that.

```
def yourscript():
    # You would need to give proper path for opening file on server, this might not work as it is
    with open('file1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as t2: # here i open 2 files and make python read it
        fileone = t1.readlines() # read lines from 1st file
        filetwo = t2.readlines() # read lines from 2nd file

    with open('difference.csv', 'w') as outFile: # create 
    output file called with update.csv
        return_string = ''
        for line in filetwo: #for statement
            if line not in fileone: # if line is not same
                return_string+=line # print the output
        return return_string
```

Comment: I updated the qs with your advice, about def my__view_name(request), I dont really understand what do you mean to put script content in there, what am doing above, is that what you meant?

Comment: So in your script, you are putiing the output in another file. Its whole another issue if you want to do that. here's what you can do a instead of outFile.write(line) --> print (line) it would print the diff line by line in terminal (command prompt).  now its upto you if you want to compile whole thing in a file or send it to browser. but make sure this terminal printing works.

Comment: I roughly updated the answer. dont expect to work as it is. This is just a blueprint.

Comment: Well thats the thing, it has to actually produce an output in .csv/.txt and later on publish this whole thing in windows server 2012 to make everyone can use it in my environment. The code that you wrote, from return_string = '' and down below til the end, does it produce an output or open in terminal?

Comment: it would put things in terminal, but you can build you code from there. If this thing writes as expected in terminal then all that is left is how to put it in file. which is a different issue./

Comment: hmm i see, its just am new at this and tbh im amazed how i got to make the website receives upload and all, and if i go down with the terminal and work from there, i dont think i will ever accomplish this. At first, my thought of process was to store file1, file2, and textprocess.py together then make a button in html that will call textprocess.py, as it finished produced a difference.csv, i make another function to push that output so the user can download it. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Okay, you are just making things complicated. Why I am saying you to print things in terminal is because that would give you sanity check that your code (textprocess.py) is working in django. If it does you can do whatever you want, you can create file, or show it on browser itself. its just about rendering from there onwards.

Comment: what is a sanity check on my code? sorry im new into django and python, also when i run the def class you created, it doesnt give me any error, just process finished with exit code 0, i believe nothing shows up because i dont use print command to print the output. So, does that mean i have to look into how to render that difference class into an output(.txt/.csv)? thanks for bearing with me

Comment: perfect. Atleast there are no errors. thats a good start. Now how do you think your script is working as expected ? you have to print it somewhere. do whatever is easiest for you.